# Segmentation Fault when trying ptr->map.clear()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a

```
struct trie {
    map< char, struct trie* > m;
};
typedef struct trie trie;
```

Then I init memory by malloc by

```
trie* root = (trie*) malloc (sizeof(trie));
```

But when I do

```
root->m.clear();
```

It gives a segmentation Fault.
I am not getting the reason why!

Comment: `(trie*) malloc (sizeof(trie));` is wrong! Should be `new trie();`. You cannot use `malloc` to initialize non POD types.

Comment: Also you should drop that c-style `typedef struct trie trie;`. You don't need that in c++.

Comment: but i have used this kind of initialization before and it works.

Comment: It may work for POD types as mentioned. But you have a `std::map` there and it requires that it's constructor is called after memory allocation. That's what `new` does.

Answer (score 1):

malloc function allocates the required memory, but it doesn't generates new objects.

**Solution 1**

Instead, use `new` keyword:

```
trie* root = new trie();
```

at the end of you program, don't forget to release it by

```
delete root;
```

**Solution 2**

Another option would be to generate this object on the stack, without pointers.
This will be done as follows:

```
trie root;
```

in this case, the memory allocated to this object will be automatically freed at the end of the scope.